# Unable To Connect Database MySql

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I'm New To PHP PDO and I have written following Code on Config.php

```
class DBConnect{
    /* defining constants for database connectivity  */
    private $host="127.0.0.1";
    private $user="root";
    private $pass="";
    private $dbname="sms-portal";

    private $dbh;
    private $error;

    public function __construct(){
        // set DSN
        $dsn='mysql:host='.$this->host.'dbname='.$this->dbname;
        //set Options

        $options= array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        // Create New PDO instance
        try{
            $this->dbh=new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
            //die("here");
        }
        // Catch any errors here
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error=$e->getMessage();
        }   
    }
}
```

Whilst working on localhost and Submitting NewUserRegistration form Its Showing Me following Warning Message.

```
Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: 
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: 
No such host is known. in config.php on line 25

Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: 
[2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: 
No such host is kn (trying to connect via tcp://127.0.0.1dbname=sms-portal:3306) 
    in config.php on line 25
```

Comment: Try updating the dsn like this ````$dsn='mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbname;````

Answer (score 2):

`$dsn='mysql:host='.$this->host.'dbname='.$this->dbname;`

Looks like you are missing a semicolon before dbname= - try this:

`$dsn='mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbname;`

Answer (score 2):

```
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

Note : You just missed ";" between host and dbname.

Comment: hello, Thanks to help me out it was exactly ;

Answer (score 1):

Add the `;` semicolon before the `dbname`:

```
$dsn='mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbname;
                            //  ^ this one
```

If you look at the error, the host isn't terminated well:

```
tcp://127.0.0.1dbname=sms-portal:3306
```